# Client can't view app in Sandbox Mode

Tags: facebook, sandbox

I have created a tab-application for a client's Facebook Page and put it in sandbox mode.
The client has a "tester" role for the app.

However, when we're trying to view the app with her Facebook User, the content appears blank like this:

[image: screenshot]

But I can view the app just fine. And the client used to be able to see it until last week.

What can the problem be? It's such a shame, since they're supposed to set it up using a built-in admin-interface.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Tobias

Comment: Can you load the same content in a canvas view instead of via the page? Have you checked the console for script errors?

Comment: Are you sure the client has **accepted the developers request** that was sent to them when you listed them as a tester? Until they accept that request they will appear in the roles section as `pending`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an SSL issue. If you don't have a signed SSL certificate yet, make sure your client has disabled secure browsing in their Facebook Account Settings > Security.